# Angular2 posting Data to nested db(mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, database

```
//user schema
{
  "firstname": "string",
  "lastname": "string",
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "status": "string",
  "created": "2017-03-22T19:39:26.530Z",
  "lastUpdated": "2017-03-22T19:39:26.531Z",
  "id": "string",
  "sites":{
      "site": {
           "sitename":"string",
           "sitepass":"string"
      }
   }
}
```

This is my mongodb Schema.
1st of all em totaly new with this all,dnt have too much idea about this.

I want to make a post request into this schema(user->sites->site->sitename) from angular2 but em not getting the right way to get into it.

I have everthing setup, i can make a post request to user->firstname || user->lastname ,but can't make post or get reqest to user->sites->site->sitename !!!!!!

`<input ng-model="??????" >`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any details so I can only guess what you have

Assuming you have a user service and are using the HTTP module to communicate to your backend, The fastest way to get to where you want to go is to have an object with the same schema as your user schema.

UserService

`class UserService {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  createUser(user) {
    return this.http.post('/users', user)
        .map(res => res.json())
  }
}`

Then in your component you can use your userService like

`this.user = {
  "firstname": "Jordan",
  "lastname": "Smith",
   ...
  "sites":{
      "site": {
           "sitename":"string",
           "sitepass":"string"
      }
  }
}
this.UserService.createUser(this.user);`

your `[(ngModel)]="user"` in this case.

again that's the best I can do with the information you gave.

I **did** notice that you have "sites"  (plural) but it is not an array. maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you are totally correct.I have made something like this.as your reply "sites" should be an array.then my schema is now

```js
{
  "firstname": "string",
  "lastname": "string",
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "status": "string",
  "created": "2017-03-22T19:39:26.530Z",
  "lastUpdated": "2017-03-22T19:39:26.531Z",
  "id": "string",
  "sites":[
      "site": {
           "sitename":"string",
           "sitepass":"string"
      }
   ]
}
```

, after it the problem is that how will i use (ngModel)]="" to pass data into "SITENAAME" and also how to show data in html tags.